# Is it possible to host a provider-hosted SharePoint app on a SharePoint server?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, iis, provider-hosted-app

I have a situation where getting additional servers will be impossible.  Could I potentially host a provider-hosted app on the same server as SharePoint?  What problems might I run into?

Comment: I haven't seen anything to the contrary, you'd most likely just want to host them on a separate port/web app. Only thing i can think of would be greater load on the server since you've got another pool running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done this with multiple solutions without any problems.

Create a new web application for the provider hosted app. Do additional configurations (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended, but it can be done.  I think there is a plethora of reasons why you don't want to do it: performance, security, etc. The whole point of it being a provider-hosted app is that it is **provider**-hosted, vs. SP hosted.

There isn't any reason it can't be on the same server, but best practices are to separate those provider-hosted apps from SharePoint.